# "It's two kilometres" or "It's two kilometres far." Are they both correct?

Tags: quantifiers

Is it grammatically correct to say "It's two kilometres far" or "town B is two kilometres far from town A?" Usually, we just omit the 'far.' But if we keep it in there, it's still correct right? My students are learning this grammar, and I want to teach it correctly!

Comment: "It's two kilometres **away**."

Comment: We do not omit the "far". There is no "far" there to omit. If you think there is a "far" there that we omit, you must not be teaching English. This is a very basic question no teacher should ever have.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth remembering that 'far' is an adjective, so we can say:

- It is far.
- It is green.

To put it after a noun phrase become problematic:

- It is 2 kilometres far.
- It is a fast dog green.

The structure tries to force the adjective into becoming a noun, which while this will work in some contexts like 'I walked the dog on the village green', it needs a certain amount of agreement among users.

For 'far' we have to consider that in the context of distance we have 'farther', which already works in the context as a strengthener:

- It is 2 kilometres farther.

The question is why would we need to use 'far' when we could use 'farther' and other equivalents, like 'away' and 'distant'?

- It is 2 kilometres away
- It is 2 kilometres distant

This is not to say that 'far' is not being used this way, or has never been used this way, but it is worth avoiding in a teaching environment when there are safer choices.

Comment: If you can't use **far** in this context because it's an adjective, why can you use **long**? Meaning 1.1 in the Oxford Dictionary https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/long

Comment: @JavaLatte it is in the explanation, I began by indicating that adding an adjective does not automatically assure a successful result. I finished by using 'distant', which is an adjective.